# ValueError in timeit module

Tags: python, timeit

I am having a difficulty using the timeit module, here is my code.

```
import timeit

setup = """
a = range(100000)
b = set(a)
"""

print timeit.timeit("a.remove(0)", setup=setup, number = 10)
print timeit.timeit("b.remove(0)", setup=setup, number = 10)
```

the last lines give me ValueError and KeyError respectively. Like the values I entered never existed at all. But when I use `print a` or `print b`. It prints the values without problem. What could possibly be my mistake here ?

**Edit:**

Here is the first error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ata\Desktop\Learn\graph theory\try.py", line 18, in <module>
    print timeit.timeit("a.remove(0)", setup=setup, number = 10)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\timeit.py", line 237, in timeit
    return Timer(stmt, setup, timer).timeit(number)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\timeit.py", line 202, in timeit
    timing = self.inner(it, self.timer)
  File "<timeit-src>", line 9, in inner
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Comment: `setup` is executed only once.  After the first time you remove 0 from the list, any subsequent attempt will raise `ValueError`.  Similarly after removing 0 from the dict.

Comment: Makes much sense! How can I overcome this problem if I want to test multiple times ?

Comment: What are you trying to time?

Comment: I was trying to time the removal time of an item from list and a set. The removal complexities are respectively O(n) and O(1) however I wanted to see the difference for myself.

Comment: There's no magical way to make a destructive operation non-destructive ;-)  I'm going to mark this as a duplicate, with a link to an older question where some alternatives are given.

Comment: If I have a better answer, should I just answer there? I think that by removing different elements you could get a better timing.

Comment: @OscarSmith, yes, no good is served by having multiple questions open asking the same thing.